# Forwarding callback from C++ to ObjC

Tags: c++, objective-c, callback, objective-c++, trampolines

I am embedding a C++ engine in an ObjC iOS project using a .mm (ObjC++).

```
// consumer.m
Wrapper* wrapper = ...;
[wrapper setupWithTarget: self
                selector: @selector(gotData:)];
-(void) gotData: (int) k {...}

//wrapper.mm
@interface Wrapper() { id targ; SEL sel; } @end
:
-(void) setupWithTarget: T
               selector: S] {
    targ = T;
    sel = S;

    cppEngine = new cppEngine(); // i.e. C++ code
    cppEngine.addCallback(
        [](int data) {
            std::cout << "got" << data;
            [targ sel: data];
        }
    );
}
```

i.e. we setup the `cppEngine` giving it a callback; here a C++ lambda.

When the engine fires the callback, we have to pass the data back through to the consumer.

My question is: what is the right architecture to do this?  I don't think `[targ sel: data];` is valid Objective C. And even if it was, I'm not sure a `SEL` is going to make it through a lambda's capture. Is it even a valid C++ object?

I can see a way of doing it by trampolining off a static method in `wrapper.mm`:

```
cppEngine.addCallback(
    [](int data) {
        [CppEngine myStaticMethod: data];
    }
);
```

... but that's starting to look icky.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the selector on the target by:

```
[targ performSelector:sel withObject:data];
```